# Is $F(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ where $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\in \Delta$,a semi-algebraic function?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, model-theory, real-algebraic-geometry

Given $$F(t_1,t_2,\dots,t_n)=\int\frac{P_1(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)}{P_2(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)}dx_1dx_2\dots dx_n$$ where  $P_1(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n), P_2(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ are polynomials whose coefficients are over $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{\bar{Q}}$ , $\Delta$ are  domain given by polynomial inequalities with coefficients  over $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{\bar{Q}}$.

Now is the function $F(t_1,t_2,\dots,t_n)$ where $(t_1,t_2,\dots,t_n)\in \Delta$,a semi-algebraic function?

Comment: Isn't $F$ a number?

Comment: @John, sorry, a typos, I have edited the post

Comment: How about this: $\int \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx = \arctan x +C$?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use the $x_1, \dots, x_n$ as arguments to $F$ on the left and integration variables on the right. Does $\Delta$ depend on the $x_i$?

Comment: @John, I have no sufficient examples of semi-algebraic function.I have to decide whether a function is semi-algebraic or not by some definition.

Comment: @anomaly, in fact $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\in \Delta$